# Update database table on grid cell value update

Tags: mysql, vb.net, devexpress

On my form i only have 2 controls, one combobox which holds names of every table in my database and one gridcontrol which shows data when table is selected in combobox.

How to update Database Table once Grid Control Cell Value Changed?

This is my code which populates the gridcontrol:

```
 Private Sub comboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles comboBox.SelectionChanged
    gridControl.ItemsSource = returnTable("select * from " & comboBox.SelectedItem("TABLE_NAME"))
End Sub

 Public Function returnTable(ByVal queryString As String)
    Dim query1 As String = queryString
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(konekcija)
        Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(query1, connection)
            Dim cmb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            table.Clear()
            adapter.Fill(table)
            Return table
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the cellvaluechanging event and update the table as explained on this 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q322494/changing-value-on-cellvaluechanging-event